# Solving dependency management issues in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

With the latest Xcode (12.5) I am facing problems with dependency management

My App is structured as follows (at least the part that is conflicting):

```
+ MainApp
+-- Shared Framework
| +- Dynamic SPM Package1 (do not embed)
|   +- Other package needed for that SPM
|
+-  Dynamic SPM Package1 (embed and sign)
    +- Other package needed for that SPM
```

So my app uses a framework. That framework itself uses one of my swift packages, which itself depends on an other one.
That swift package is also used in my main app and there it's embed&signed.
In my framework it's marked as `No not embed`.

So now when I build my product and inspect it, in it's frameworks folder, I see my Shared Framework. Inside that shared framework in it's frameworks folder I don't see the `Dynamic SPM Package1` which is good, cause I told Xcode do not embed... Good... But what I can see, is the other package needed for that SPM. Bad... why is it there, when the framework that needs it, is also do not embed?

How can I tell Xcode not to do that?
Again... with the previous Version of Xcode (12.4) it worked. So seems to be a change there...?!?

Answer (score 0):

If you control all the frameworks and packages, I think you can solve this problem by setting up your Swift Package products as `.dynamic` libraries:
https://docs.swift.org/package-manager/PackageDescription/PackageDescription.html#product

Make sure to do the usual dance of removing derived data, resetting SPM cache and updating to latest package versions before rebuilding.

In this screenshot the first package (NYPLUtilities) specifies a `.dynamic` product:
[image]

If any of those other packages are third party dependencies (and so you can't really edit the Package product definition without forking, e.g. PureLayout in the screenshot above), then it's more complicated. If the Package does not explicitly specify a `.dynamic` product, Xcode 12/13.1 always seems to embed it when adding it to an Xcode project, even if the official SPM documentation states:

```
/// A library's product can either be statically or dynamically linked.
/// If possible, don't declare the type of library explicitly to let 
/// the Swift Package Manager choose between static or dynamic linking based
/// on the preference of the package's consumer.
```

I have found 2 workarounds for this:

1. create a shell framework target that includes all the Swift Packages you don't control. Link your app and your other frameworks (that depend on those) dynamically. More info here: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-link-a-swift-package-as-dynamic/32062
2. Manually modify the Xcode project to remove the embed phase but leave the link phase: https://forums.swift.org/t/is-this-an-xcode-bug-or-somehow-related-to-spm/33987/3

Hopefully Apple will address this issue in a future version of Xcode.